# Are Solr's caches created in the JVM's heap memory or in off-heap (direct) memory?

Tags: caching, memory-management, solr

I've looked for an answer to this but haven't found one. [The official Solr documentation on cache](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching) doesn't say anything on this, and while the [official docs on Performance Issues](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors) touch a bit on heap and memory consumption, they still don't specify how cache is handled.

I think it's an important question, because when configuring large caches, clearly it's them that'll take the most memory as compared to other Solr components/actions, so it'd be nice to know if I should adjust the JVM max heap parameter (Xmx) or the direct memory parameter (-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solr caches are on the JVM Heap.

Heliosearch, a Solr fork that is currently a drop-in replacement, does store the filter caches off-heap.

Comment: Solr's blockcache is off-heap by default, but it's only used with HDFS. See `solr.hdfs.blockcache.direct.memory.allocation` [documented here](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/search/1-3-0/Cloudera-Search-User-Guide/csug_tuning_solr.html).